# Update theory data after qed of thy_goal_defn keyword

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to update some custom theory data after the obligation introduced by a thy_goal_defn keyword has been satisfied.

As an example, if I have a `data` keyword, which opens a simple proof for the term given. And I have a `print_data` keyword that just prints out the state of the theory data.

```
data example:
  "(x::int) < y ⟹ x ≤ y"
  by simp

data example2:
  "(x::int) > 0 ⟹ x ≥ 0"
  by simp

print_data
```

Then in the above, the `print_data` keyword would just show

```
example: x < y ⟹ x ≤ y
example2: 0 < x ⟹ 0 ≤ x
```

I've been trying to understand how to implement this but thus far I'm only able to update the theory data while the obligation is being proved, i.e. the following will print `example: x < y ⟹ x ≤ y` as expected.

```
data example:
  "(x::int) < y ⟹ x ≤ y"
  print_data
  by simp
```

My approach to implementing this has been as follows:

1. Declare the keywords at the start of the theory

```
theory ProvedData
  imports Main
keywords
  "data" :: thy_goal_defn and
  "print_data" :: diag
begin
```

2. Implement a simple structure to store the data. Here the merge logic is incomplete but I suspect not the culprit, as I am able to simulate adding multiple elements to the structure using ML code.

```
type data =
  {name: string, expression: term}

signature DATA_LIST =
sig
  val get: theory -> data list
  val add: data -> theory -> theory
  val reset: theory -> theory
end;

structure DataList: DATA_LIST =
struct

structure DataStore = Theory_Data
(
  type T = data list;
  val empty = [];
  val extend = I;
  val merge = Library.merge (fn (_) => true);
);

val get = DataStore.get;

fun add t thy = DataStore.map (cons t) thy

val reset = DataStore.put [];

end;
```

3. Finally, I implement a simple function to initiate the proof state and to update the theory data.

```
fun open_data_goal
  ((bind: binding, _), exp: string) ctxt = 
  let
    val prop = Syntax.read_prop ctxt exp;
    val term = Syntax.read_term ctxt exp;
 
    val register = DataList.add {name=Binding.print bind, expression=term}

    fun after_qed _ ctxt =
      (Proof_Context.background_theory register ctxt)
  in
    Proof.theorem NONE after_qed [[(prop, [])]] 
      (Proof_Context.background_theory register ctxt)
  end

val _ =
  Outer_Syntax.local_theory_to_proof \<^command_keyword>‹data›
    "define an data and open proof obligation"
    (Parse_Spec.thm_name ":"
     -- Parse.term
     >> open_data_goal);
```

Here I have used the same data update logic for both, initiating the proof state and the after_qed callback. The logic during initiation is what allows the data to be printed mid-way through the proof.

I believe what I am specifically confused about is how to update the top level theory within the after_qed function. What would be the recommended approach to achieve this goal?

Minimal working example of the problem: https://gist.github.com/BraeWebb/ac6b73354e61736e11836e655c69b507

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I have little time to investigate this problem in detail. However, I expect that using `Local_Theory.background_theory` would be a better solution for `after_qed`. Nonetheless, some of this looks slightly suspicious to my eyes (are you certain that you need `Theory_Data` for your application? what is the expected behavior when `data` is invoked from a local context with assumptions?). My advice would be to state a more general problem that you are trying to solve and ask someone on the mailing list to review this code.

Comment: `Local_Theory.background_theory` works perfectly! I feel foolish for not discovering this earlier. Thank you very much.
I agree that the use case feels suspicious, the end goal is to define a suite of optimizations that have to be proved when introduced but can be code generated into an optimization suite at a later stage. I suspect I should get some feedback from the mailing list if this is the right approach. Thanks again for your help.